# How can I get rid of this Notice: Undefined index:

Tags: php

I was wondering if anyone knows how to fix this Notice: Undefined index:page message I'm getting?

The notice is coming from the first line: `$page = $_GET["page"];`

```
  $page = $_GET["page"];
  if ($page)
      $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;
  else
      $start = 0;
```

I'm running a pagination script and I only get the Notice when I'm at the main url.
Example `mypage.php` When I switch to page `mypage.php?page=1` I do not get the notice.

Comment: Change the first line to , `$page = isset($_GET["page"])?$_GET["page"]:FALSE;`

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran thank you that worked. Put it as an answer and I mark it correct.

Comment: cwd, @Sam's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22878210/1003917) is correct too , you can accept that.

Comment: Yeah I just tried that method out and worked great. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the page parameter `isset()` first. Instead of `$page = $_GET['page']`, use `$page = isset($_GET['page'])? $_GET['page'] : 1;`.  This requires some previous knowldege:

- [`$_GET`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) variables won't show up unless they are passed in the URL.
- [`isset()`](https://www.php.net/isset) checks to see if a variable is set.
- Shorthand conditional statements make this prettier by setting the page variable on one line:

  - `$page = isset($_GET['page'])? $_GET['page'] : 1;`
  - If `$_GET['page']` is set, then `$page` should equal that value, **otherwise** the default page is `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace first line with this

```
$page = isset($_GET["page"]) ? $_GET["page"] : FALSE;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set error reporting with `& ~E_NOTICE` or do like say guys:

```
  if (isset($_GET["page"]))
      $start = (intval($_GET["page"]) - 1) * $limit;
  else
      $start = 0;
```